# What does R in power of HxWx3 mean?

Tags: metric-spaces, notation, relations, real-numbers

I was reading an article and this sentence was unclear to me:

An encoder-based generative model is a function $G : z → x$ that generates an image $x \in R^{H \times W\times3}$ from a latent representation $z \in R^{h \times w\times |z|}$. What does $R^{H \times W\times3}$ mean? I know that $R$ mean real numbers.

Comment: Note that you can make a special character $\mathbb R$ for the real numbers in $\LaTeX$ with `\mathbb R`.

Comment: height width and probably 3 color bands